# test for null not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement

I have a an onclick function, inside this function I want to create a condition for the way some elements are shown in the textarea. added this in the function:

```
    bPlace = bookForm.txtPlace.value;
    if (bPlace="null") {
        bPlace="!."
    }

bookForm.myText.value = bPlace
```

according to this condition when the value in txtPlace in myForm is not null it should show anything the user puts in. But when I test it, when I type something, instead of showing that, it still shows the ((  !.  )) in the textarea.

I should say I used "Undefined" instead of Null and still the same thing happened

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. You need to do `bPlace=="null"`.

Comment: `bPlace="null"` assigs the string `null` to `bPlace` and returns the string which is truthy so always the `if` block will get executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using assignment operator instead of comparision operator

The statement `bPlace="null"` will assign the string `null` to `bPlace` and will return it, which is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value so the if block will always get executed.

```
bPlace = bookForm.txtPlace.value;
if (bPlace == "null") {
    bPlace = "!."
}

bookForm.myText.value = bPlace
```

But since `bPlace` is a input value, I think what you are trying to do is if the input is left blank you want to put a default value in that case you can check

```
bPlace = bookForm.txtPlace.value;
if (!bPlace) {
    bPlace = "!."
}

bookForm.myText.value = bPlace
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lcor89bq/)

Which can be further shorten to

```
bookForm.myText.value = bookForm.txtPlace.value || '!.';
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lcor89bq/2/)

Comment: Thanks I added the = . but now the if doesn't work! when I don't enter any inputs it doesn't show the !. in the textarea!

Comment: @aryazdani then see the second solution

Comment: @ArunPJohny The second solution isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek why?

Comment: @ArunPJohny There is no `String.IsNullOrEmpty` in JavaScript, that's from C#.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek that is not my answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny My misunderstanding, I assumed by "second solution" you meant the second answer.